# ubuntu is redirecting all virtual hosts to https?

Tags: php, virtual

I have made a virtual host on Ubuntu and It is redirecting it to https. 
and virtual hosts not working.

here is virtual host settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName xserver.dev
     DocumentRoot /var/www/xserver/public
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory /var/www/xserver/public>
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xx-error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xx-access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

i have added it in /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 xserver.dev

when I try to access xserver.dev 
It is redirecting me to https://xserver.dev and blank page

I am unable to access file files too. which are available on the given path

Comment: Check your `.htaccess`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.dev` is a top-level domain name operated by Google.
Since Chrome 63, and Firefox [59](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/59), the browsers redirects the `.dev` URLs to HTTPS.

It is recommended to use `.test`, reserved by the Internet Engineering Task Force since 1999 ([RFC2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606)).

Change you virtual host to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName xserver.test
     DocumentRoot /var/www/xserver/public
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory /var/www/xserver/public>
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xx-error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xx-access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

And your `/etc/hosts` to:

```
127.0.0.1 xserver.test
```

Then, access to your website : http://xserver.test